# Reading OTP automatically on Android

Tags: android, server, one-time-password

I am working on an Android App, in which server sends an OTP and the user needs to enter this OTP in the App, to SignUp for my App, What I want is, that my App should be able to automatically read the OTP sent by the server. .I am trying to implement auto detect OTP to edit text when OTP is received,  I tried but nothing hapening any please help me to find out the error

Readsms.class

```
public class ReadSms extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {

            if (bundle != null)
            {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++)
                {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber ;
                    String message = currentMessage .getDisplayMessageBody();

                    try
                    {

                        if (senderNum.equals("AZ-PSDSSL"))
                        {

                         Otp Sms = new Otp();
                            Sms.recivedSms(message );
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

Otp.class

```
class Otp extends Activity {


    TextView otp;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);
         otp=findViewById(R.id.otpid);

    }
    public void recivedSms(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            otp.setText(message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

OTPActivity.java

```
if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
            // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
        }
 private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

        int receiveSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);

        int readSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (receiveSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS);
        }
        if (readSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        }
        if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
     <receiver android:name=".ReadSms" >
                <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: is it giving any error in logcat ?

Comment: no error showing in logcat

Comment: `Otp Sms = new Otp();` here you are creating a new object of your activity, so it is not working as expected. What you need to do is , you need to implement Interface to achieve, what you want.

Comment: how is it duplicate bro?  Lucifer .. if you can Answer this question using that answer

Comment: your question is duplication of that linked one, However your actual problem is, how to send data from broadcast receiver to your activity's edittext.

Comment: hmm qstn maybe same but method code etc are dff